# How to read and write excel data through .net

Tags: .net

How to read one excel file and write the content of the excel file to another excel file?

Comment: Do want to copy the whole file or just some of the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Open Office XML SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

The benefit of this is that you can create a spreadsheet without having Excel on the system.